# Height map to cube

Tags: modifiers, knife-tool

I have an textured object that looks approximately like this.

[image]

It is one-sided, like  a height map. I want to make sort of a cube out of it.  And I want to keep the texture.

How could I do it?

I tried to add *Boolean Modifier*, and got "didn't manage to link up hole!" error, I think I am doing something wrong.

EDIT:

I think the easiest way to explain it:I want this sort of thing to seat on top of the cube. But if I just put it on top there will be holes at the sides.

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. Can't you make a Cube, UV unwrap it and apply this texure on it?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking. Is your *textured object* a plane, and you want to convert it to a modeled relief? If so, one approach would be to extrude the four corners of your plane to the back, and create the back face.

Comment: Can you show a print screen of what you currently have?

Comment: @brasshat, no, no, my object is not a plane, it is already a height map, or probably it is more common to call it relief.   OK, I think I could choose 4 corners and extrude. Although they don't lie on a plane, because they have different height.  But how do I close the sides?

Comment: @LukeD it is because I have a height map, not a plane. or a landscape, a relief. I'm not sure how 3D modeling community calls it.

Comment: Could you provide blend file? It's hard to understand for me what is your goal.

Comment: @LukeD I can't really, because it is not my model. But I added an image, maybe it is more clear now what I mean?

Comment: Put that "thing" on top of the cube, select the border loop, and bridge it with top loop of the cube ?

Comment: @MrZak yes, that's essentially what I want to do! The problem is, I also I need to crop it, just like one would crop the image. I also tried to select the border, but it is  not trivial, because mesh is very irregular. So it is because of this two things, that I thought boolean might solve it

Comment: @MrZak, to be precise, I struggle to select the border, because I can't get the damn thing into orthogonal view. I tried to do it (see my previous post on which you also commented), but I think orientation computed just on one face was't good enough for the whole mesh.

Comment: In general, you don't need to have thing aligned in ortographic view to select border loop; you can use [selection tools](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html) like `Alt` with clicking (loops) or `Ctrl` with click (shortest path). Some complex cases can of course make this task tedious; you could mix it with hiding part of mesh etc.

Comment: @MrZak OK, so I can select shortest path between vertices? Amazing, thanks a lot!  But how would you go around cropping then? because I thought that cube will do the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favourite approach to this is using Knife project. It is a little involved, but so are the other methods. Let's say we have this piece of art here to 'cubify':

[image: piece of art]

Start off with adding a plane underneath:

[image: plane]

In Top view, scale this plane so it is just inside the geometry you want to cubify:

[image: geo]

Now in Object Mode, select the plane, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the object you want to cut. Now tab into Edit Mode. Select all polygons using <kbd>A</kbd> and execute the Knife Project function. It will cut your selection with the other object you had selected before you went into Edit Mode (the plane):

[image: knife project]

the result is:

[image: result]

invert the selection using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>:

[image: Inverted]

Now delete these faces to get this result:

[image: result]

If you check this in Textured View, you'll see the textures are still intact. Next, select all faces again, and run the **Select Boundary Loop** operator from the menu:

[image: select boundary loop]

Extrude this loop downwards, and set the 3D cursor as the Pivot Center as the next step:

[image: loop extruded]

Scale this down on the Z-Axis by activating <kbd>S</kbd>, then type in <kbd>0</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should see this:

[image: bottom open]

To close the hole in a reasonable fashion, you can either hit <kbd>F</kbd> if you have the **F2 Addon** enabled, or use **Grid Fill** alternatively. To use Grid Fill, select two opposite sides of the open square first:

[image: selection]

Now hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, and search for **Grid Fill**. After Execution, you should have a closed volume:

[image: final result]

Comment: What could be the reason that only a small subset of faces gets selected after knife project? I used orthoview.

Comment: @Noidea It uses the view Vector, but you might be looking down the model with 'Perspective' turned on. Make sure you are in 'Orthographic' mode, hit NumPad 5 to toggle between the two. On one of my screenshots it ready 'Top Ortho', that's what it should be.

Comment: Yes, strange... I am trying it in ortho mode. Using boundary loop I also get all sharp edges on the surface selected. I expected only the outer edges will be selected. Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Actually not even sharp, just any edge with angle > 0 between faces.

Comment: @Noidea the only explanation for that would be that the mesh on the inside contains open areas, i.e. vertices which are not merged. In other words, holes. It depends on the mesh if it is simpler to box-deselect the inner region, or alternatively use shortest path select (was mentioned in comments before)

Comment: @Noidea Try 'remove doubles' as well, maybe the mesh isn't merged together at all?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It had plenty of doubles! I have far fewer edges considered as the boundary now, but many are still there, mostly of one orientation. And knife project now works much better, picking up a lot more faces. But I still have about 15 holes in the knife project selection. This mesh is nuts. Maybe I wasn't able to delete all duplicates?

Comment: You can Try to raise The threshold for removing doubles. Press F6 right after running The operator, then enter a higher tolerance value. Be careful not to raise it too far

Comment: Oh, that's useful. I was able to delete more. I raised the threshold quite high in the end, so the mesh started to collapse badly, but many edges are still boundary! I don't see visually, how they can be as far from each other as the threshold I used.

Comment: Ok, I also had non-manifold geometry, this was causing it.  Thanks again.